# Kiel mallongigi kunmetitajn vortojn?

Tags: word-formation, writing

En Esperanto, oni mallongigas nomojn aŭ esprimojn, plejparte uzante la komencan literon de ĉiu vorto en la nomo/esprimo, ekz.:

> **UEA** = Universala Esperanto-Asocio
>
> **TEJO** = Tutmonda Esperantista Junulara Organizo

Kiel oni mallongigas tiajn nomojn aŭ esprimojn, se unu el la vortoj estas kunmetita? Jen hazarda ekzemplo:

> Plursistema Komputila Rolludo

Kiel oni ĝin mallongigas?

- **PKR** — Preni nur la komencan literon el ĉiu vorto
- **PSKRL** — Preni ankaŭ la komencajn literojn de la subvortoj, *majusklaj*
- **PsKRl** — Preni ankaŭ la komencajn literojn de la subvortoj, *minusklaj*

Ĉu ekzistas regulo pri ĉi tio, aŭ ĉu oni ĝin faras laŭplaĉe?

Comment: Ankaŭ „Tutmonda” estas kunmetita vorto, kaj tamen oni skribas TEJO kaj ne TMEJO. Vi mem donis la respondon al via demando ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Ne ekzistas unu fiksita maniero fari tiajn mallongigojn. Kiel Paŭl Peeraerts rimarkis, "Tutmonda" estas kunmetita vorto, tamen neniu diras "TmEJO". Sed en "Nord-Amerika Somera Kurso", "Nord-Amerika" estas kunmetita vorto, sed oni mallongigas ĝin "NASK" kaj ne "NSK". Farante mallongigojn por organizoj, eventoj, kaj aliaj aferoj, oni konsideras, interalie, memoreblon, belaspektecon, kaj foje elparoleblon. Por fari mallongigojn por oftaj vortoj kaj frazpartoj, ekzemple "kaj tiel plu", "bonvolu", kaj "ridego" (uzate simile al angla ROFL), la reguloj ŝajne estas eĉ pli nebulaj; oni uzas jen la unuan literon de ĉiu vorto (ktp), jen la unuan leteron de ĉiu radiko (bv), kaj iufoje eĉ malpli senchavajn rimedojn (rdg) (tamen tiuj lastaj ja estas malpli oftaj).

Answer (score 2):

> atm = antaŭtagmeze
>
> ptm = posttagmeze
>
> bv = bonvolu
>
> TTT = Tut-Tera Teksaĵo

[http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq170.html](http://pages.ucsd.edu/%7Edkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq170.html)